# 2 monitor set up on MacBook Pro with just 1 unused ThunderBolt port

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, display, thunderbolt, daisy-chaining

I started work at a new organization and have been provided with a 2017 13" MacBook Pro with 2 Thunderbolt ports. Those are the only two ports on the device apart from a 3.5 mm jack. One of the TB port is always occupied by a YubiKey which is a security device which needs to be plugged into the laptop for me to access office resources. I have read that Macs don't support daisy chaining so is there any way that I can have a 2 monitor set up with just 1 TB port ?

Answer (score 1):

Macs do support daisy-chaining over Thunderbolt. Depending on whether your monitors can be daisy-chained, you can either daisy-chain them or use a USB-C or Thunderbolt Hub to gain additional ports.
You could also plug in your YubiKey into one of the monitors if it has a built in hub.

Comment: Hubs are not always reliable to support such an approach. Perhaps the hub has a lower protocol than required or the intermediate cable from the hub to the computer has a lower protocol than required. Prefer to keep the key directly in the computer and expand with a properly configured thunderbolt hub.